# What happened if I put def into the with statement python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a mysql client class like below:
`mysql/client.py`

```
import pymysql
import logger
class MySQLClient(object):

def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port, charset='utf8mb4'):
    self.host = host
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.database = database
    self.port = port
    self.charset = charset
    self.cnx = None
    self.cursor = None

def __enter__(self):
    self.connect()
    return self

def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
    if self.cursor:
        self.cursor.close()
    if self.cnx:
        self.cnx.close()
    print("Exited")

def connect(self):
    try:
        self.cnx = pymysql.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.user,
            password=self.password,
            database=self.database,
            port=self.port,
            charset=self.charset
        )
        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            "ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
        raise e

def execute(self, stmt):
    try:
        if self.cnx is None or self.cnx.cursor is None or not self.cnx.open:
            self.connect()
        self.cursor.execute(stmt)
        return self.cursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error when execute query: " + stmt)
        raise e
```

in `mysql_repo.py` file, I define two function like this:

```
from mysql.client import MySQLClient
with MySQLClient(rds_host, user, password, payment_db_name, port) as client:
   def insert_user():
      client.execute(insert_user_query)
   def insert_company():
      client.execute(insert_company_query)
```

and in `job.py`, I call two function `insert_user` and `insert_company` above like:

```
def execute():
   mysql_repo.insert_user()
   mysql_repo.insert_company()
```

When execute function, every thing is fine, but it look like mysql connection is not closed.
What I want to know is when mysql connection is closed?

Thank you!!

Comment: why are you defining the functions there? it makes little sense

Comment: Anyway, it should not affect the behavior of the `with` block, `__exit__` should still be called when it finishes. Add some prints

Comment: sorry, i'm edited. I'm defining them there because they are execute insert query fucntion

Comment: function definition != function execution. You can define the function outside the `with` block but call it inside

Comment: How can I do this? Can you show me an example in this case?